# IntelliJ Producs go to last opening bracket when pressing Alt + Gr + 8 ([)

Tags: intellij-idea, keyboard-shortcuts, webstorm

I have IntelliJ Idea 15 IU-143.381 and Webstorm WS-143.381

Given you have the following code:

```
int[] i = new int[3];
```

at some point (fixed after restart but coming again quite quickly....) I cannot do this simple thing, because I am on a German layout keyboard. For inserting a `[` does not work any more.

I need to press <kbd>Alt Gr</kbd> + <kbd>8</kbd> to type a `[`.

This results into jumping to the last opening `}`
for example. I have typed this:

```
public void foo(){
int
```

On pressing the `[` the cursor moves from after `int` in the second row to the position after `foo(){`. This is continued till you are up in the class's opening brackets [in Java]. I have tried it in Webstorm with JS and there it is the same. Anyone has an idea how to fix this?

I am on Windows 10 64-bit, German UI and keyboard layout.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Reset IntelliJ/Webstorm/another Jetbrains product's settings by deleting the user preferences folder (for exemple `C:\Users\[user]\.IdeaC-[version]` in Windows), then when you are told about "smart keyboard shortcuts", then just ignore it and it will never reappear again.

**Just remember that this will reset your other preferences too.**

Comment: I have the same problem but only on IDEA 15. I installed the community edition on two different PCs (w7 and w10) and both have this problem. My Android Studio-branded installation of IDEA14 doesn't have this bug.

Comment: For IntelliJ Idea 15 delete the folder C:\Users\YourUserName\.IdeaIC15 and for PyCharm delete C:\Users\Chris\.PyCharm50 and so forth. Works great :) Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 3):

I had the same issue with Android Studio 2.0, which is based on IntelliJ. I'm using a Swiss German keyboard layout, on which in have to press <kbd>Alt Gr</kbd><kbd>ü</kbd> to write a bracket `[`, and <kbd>Alt Gr</kbd><kbd>!</kbd> for a `]` respectively.

For some reason this matches the keyboard shortcut for *"Move Caret to Code Block Start"*, which was registered as <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>[</kbd>. Same for *"Move Caret to Code Block End"* with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>]</kbd>. Looks like IntelliJ cannot handle this correctly.

To fix the issue, I simply removed those shortcuts in *File > Settings > Keymap*.